# init function inside serializer class in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, instance, init

This is a question of comprehension rather than code issue. I came across a code snippet of other person who has used init function inside the serializer class. I had to write update code on it. I wrote overriding the update method inside that serializer class which is as follows:

```
class ProfileInfoApiview(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileInfoSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

My serializer that i have wrote:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["name", "mobile","user_type"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("iam init")
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].required = True

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        print("iam update")
        user = instance
        user_type = validated_data.get("user_type")
        if user_type:
            if user_type == "student":
                Student.objects.create(user=user)
            if user_type == "parent":
                Parent.objects.create(user=user)
            if user_type == "teacher":
                Teacher.objects.create(user=user)
        instance.save()
        super(ProfileSerializer,self).update(instance,validated_data)
        return instance
```

The confusion here is the init function that was written above. I just wrote the update function. The init was there already. Even if I remove the init function it works as expected and even I keep it there, it works fine. The print command is working that means init is working. But what is its use there?? If it does something why it is working when I removed it?? When is the init function called here in serializer?? I know the init function is called when an instance is created in general python but cant relate that to here.

Comment: In this case, it alters `required` attribute of all the initialised fields (ie. `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` does the job of initialising all the fields).

Comment: This is useful when you want to add dynamic fields to the form,  pop up the fields based upon the user request, etc

Comment: can you make it clear avinash by giving an example avinash

Answer (score 1):

It is a way to know which fields should be updated in the "update" function. For example, in your case you have:

```
fields = ["name", "mobile", "user_type"]
```

This means that the only fields you expect are those 3. This can be useful in the update using "self.fields" to know which ones you have to update from the Model: "User". It is especially useful if the model has many more fields than the 3 indicated so you only make sure to update the ones defined in "fields".

You could not use the "init" because if you know what fields you expect and you have it controlled in the function, it would not be necessary.